# Pass variable from Javascript to PHP using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to pass in variables from a Javascript file to a PHP file.
From my js file:

```
dataQuery = {
    range: [[range.lower, range.upper]],
    detail: { id: detail.id }
  };

 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    url: scope.fetchUrl,
    data: { query: dataQuery }
    })
    .done(function( data ) {
        alert("success!");
    }
```

In my php file I have session variables because I need to do oauth authentication.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['accessToken'])) 
{
    $companyId = "1234";
    $rollupFreq = "1H";
    $oauth->setToken(
        $_SESSION['accessToken'],
        $_SESSION['accessTokenSecret']);
    $apiUrl = ($apiBaseUrl
                . '&company_id=' . urlencode($companyId) 
                . '&rollup_frequency=' . urlencode($rollupFreq) 
                . '&start_datetime_utc=' . urlencode($range['lower'])
                . '&end_datetime_utc=' . urlencode($range['upper'])
                );
    try
    {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');       

        $data = $oauth->fetch($apiUrl);
        $responseInfo = $oauth->getLastResponse();
        print_r($responseInfo);
        if (isset($_GET['query']))
        {
            $range = $_GET['query'];
            print_r($range);
            }
    }
}
```

Nothing appears when I try to print $range, and when I try to use values from $range in the url I get "Undefined variable: range in url"

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating an AJAX request using ***POST***:

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     //...
 });
```

Yet in your PHP code, you use the `$_GET` variable:

```
$range = $_GET['query'];
```

Change `$_GET` to `$_POST`.

You're also using the `$range` variable (in `urlencode($range['upper'])` for example), but there's no code anywhere that actually declares, let alone initializes it. That's the cause of the *"Undefined variable"* notices you're seeing

Lastly, the data you're sending to PHP will look something like this:

```
$_POST['query']['range'] = array(
    array(range.lower, range.upper)//whatever these values may be
);
```

So to get at the `range.lower` value, you'd have to write:

```
$_POST['query']['range'][0][0];
//for the upper:
$_POST['query']['range'][0][1];
```

That's just messy. [see the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax): jQuery will correctly format your data for you, regardless of what you pass to `$.ajax`. I'd suggest the following:

```
dataQuery = {
    range: {lower: range.lower, upper: range.upper},
    detail: { id: detail.id }
};

 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    //async: true, <== you can leave this out
    url: scope.fetchUrl,
    data: dataQuery
}).done(function( data ) {
    alert("success!");
});
```

Then, in PHP, you can get at the values a bit more intuitively:

```
$upper = $_POST['range']['upper'];
//to get a range array:
$rage = range(
    (int) $_POST['range']['lower'],//these values are strings so cast
    (int) $_POST['range']['upper'] //to ints to get a numeric range
);
$detailId = $_POST['detail']['id'];
```

Comment: You're right about the POST/GET, thank you. But I'm confused about using $range, how do I access the lower & upper values that were passed in from js?

Comment: @user2100620: Updates my answer, ATM, that's `$_POST['query']['range'][0][0]` and `$_POST['query']['range'][0][1]`, because `dataQuery.range` is declared as a 2D array (`[[` <== 2 `[` means 2 arrays).

Comment: I've done exactly as you've said and I'm still getting "Undefined variable: lower/upper in url" when I try to use the values from $lower & $upper in the api call

Comment: @user2100620: With the code I've posted here, there won't be a `$lower` or `$upper` anywhere. Set up a pastebin or a gist or something so I can actually _see_ what you're doing. The JS and the PHP code both, because if you do what I've posted here, things should work

Comment: http://pastebin.com/NXPWU0w8 There are obviously things missing from the Javascript section, because there are many other things going on

Comment: @user2100620: The first time you use `$upper` is on line 102, but you're not declaring nor initializing it anywhere. There should be a line like `$upper = isset($_POST['range']['upper']) ? $_POST['range']['upper'] : 0;` before that. You can't use a variable unless it's been declared. That's the problem you have